# Ubuntu 17.04: no new shell window

Tags: command-line, unity

Since my laptop has Ubuntu 17.04, I can't open a second shell window. The option "New Terminal" in the Unity bar is gone. This is very inconvenient, as I usually have a number of shell windows open. 
What can I do to get the "New Terminal" option back?

Comment: Why in the world this question has 2 close votes as off-topic ? 17.04 is supported, user is using Unity desktop. Perfectly on-topic

Comment: If you have your terminal window selected (Active) and press ctrl+shift+n does it open a new terminal window?

Comment: I found I can open a new terminal window from the existing terminal window. It's more cumbersome, but it works :-)